# Deep linking callback issues in iOS11

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios11, url-scheme, openurl

I have implemented deep linking in my app using URL schema **which is working properly in all versions of iOS except 11**. The issue is when I load **AppURLSchema://** in the device browser it launches the app but **none of the appDelegate methods gets called to get the deep linking URL** so that I can perform deep linking so that user will be able to see different content based upon the URL.

None of the following functions are getting called:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

**This is not an issue on iOS 10, it seems to have been introduced in iOS 11.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: what about the third option

Comment: It's deprecated.. Not getting called in iOS11

Comment: The first option is the most up to date protocol, as I'm sure you know, so it should be getting called. This could be a shot in the dark because they're only used for Universal links but is `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:` getting called?

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/19 swizzling is terrible for debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just Configuring Firebase SDK causing this issue. With Firebase SDK it's working fine but There is Localytics SDK also integrated in my app and there is some conflict between FIREBASE and LOCALYTICS SDKs due to which my app was not getting the callback.

So I just removed Firebase framework based upon the priority and everything started working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same problem and I discovered that the SDK Firebase integrated in my app is blocking the following callback: `application:openURL:options`.

Without configuring Firebase, all is working ok.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Localytics Documentation](https://docs.localytics.com/dev/ios.html#handling-universal-links-ios), integrations for both platforms can lead to conflicts, particularly around the handling of deeplinks.

You can prevent Firebase from swizzling the methods in your AppDelegate by adding **FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled** set to **NO** in your app's info.plist as described in [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in).